# Rules Object Model: Declarative vs POJO

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I have read that is wise to keep the Rules Object Model separate from the Business Layer Object Model. drools-guvnor supports two models: declarative and POJO. Which is better to use in a large enterprise app?

The envisaged architecture consists of Presentation+Business Layer on one app server and guvnor with a wrapper web service on another, where the Rules WS exposes SOAP web API for the business logic to validate the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer POJO. If there is too many models and many attributes in one model, it would be an arduous work with declarative in guvnor. POJO would be more flexible and easier in your IDE. When model need changes, you should upload the POJO jar again.